# function argument is geting a wrong value after function entry

Tags: gcc

gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)

Upon entering a function one of the arguments is getting a wrong value. The value is always same. I cannot create the issue with a smaller test case but maybe someone out there has an idea what is going on. Function name and the arg names have been changed.

Just before calling the below function I am printing the stack and the values of the arguments:

arg1 is integer with the value 0

arg2 is a pointer to a structure with the value NULL

arg3 is integer with value 0

arg4 is a pointer to integer

0x80763960:     0x0000000000000000      **0x0000000045603280**

0x80763970:     0x0000000080763af0      0x00000000010a03ed

**func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);**

The **bold** address 0x80763968 contains the value of arg3 and I have placed a watch point on this address.

Upon entering the function the gdb says:

Hardware watchpoint 86: *(int*)0x80763968

Old value = 1163932288

New value = 0

0x00000000018574e5 in func(arg1=0, arg2=0x0, arg3=0, arg4=0x45603e68)

6214    {

(gdb) s

Breakpoint 58, func (arg1=0, arg2=0x0, **arg3=30**, arg4=0x80763f1c)

When I print the address of arg3 and the value on stack, I see the below:

(gdb) p &arg3

$703 = (int *) 0x80763968

0x80763960:     0x0000000000000000      **0x000000000000001e**

The question is where is this **0x1e** coming from?

Comment: Look at the disassembly.